# Filling background color in excel rows using Java apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read a excel sheet and fill the background color for rows using following code:

```
....
HSSFCellStyle cellStyle1 = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle1.setFillForegroundColor(new HSSFColor.BLACK().getIndex());
cellStyle1.setFillBackgroundColor(new HSSFColor.RED().getIndex());
cellStyle1.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

for(int i=0;i < rowCount;i++){
     sheet.getRow(i).setRowStyle(cellStyle1);
}
...
```

when I run my code, the color is getting filled for only blank cells. For all cells which contains data there is no change in color. Can someone tell me why it is happening?

Comment: @Sebastian_H hey... it's not duplicate. Please compare both questions.

Comment: On  a second look the questions really are different enough. I removed my previous comments.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, set setFillForegroundColor is for setting cell background color. Comment out setFillBackgroundColor and it should work.

```
CellStyle cellStyle1 = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle1.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.index);
//cellStyle1.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.index);
cellStyle1.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

Edited**

Working test code

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;


public class TestPoi {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Started");
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("input.xls"));

        CellStyle cellStyle1 = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle1.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.index);
        //cellStyle1.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.index);
        cellStyle1.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
             Row row = rowIterator.next();
             Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
             while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                 Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                 cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle1);
                 /*HSSFCellStyle style = (HSSFCellStyle)cell.getCellStyle();
                 style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.index);*/
                 System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
             }
        }
        workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("output.xls"));
        System.out.println("Ended");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your sample code, where you try to set the style in a cell ? as it's working for me. I'm posting my test code.

Comment: There are three tiers of color in a cell. The font color (which some consider to be the cell foreground), and two colors for the fill (which some consider to be the cell background). A fill has a pattern, a foreground color, and a background color. The pattern shows in the foreground color over the background color. When the pattern is a solid color, the solid foreground color is all that is displayed for the fill.

Answer (score 0):

**In short: `setRowStyle` is not doing what you assume it does.**

All it does ([see source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi/3.9/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.java#HSSFRow.setRowStyle%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle%29)) is register the style as the rows default style.

```
  row.setFormatted(true);
  row.setXFIndex(style.getIndex());
```

It does not iterate over all the cells in a row and changes their style. Thus the style only applies to not existing cells(*1*) and newly created cells which reference the row style by default.

As you can see from the code above styles are simply referenced by their index. In order to allow for different styles on the row and various cells, the cells must be able to reference a different style. The cell style then logically supersedes the row style. Thus to apply a style to all cells you must assign the style not only to the row but to all existing cells as well.

You said in your question that you are reading the document and then you try to color the row. So I will assume that your not actually creating new cells yourself, because POI should then copy the row style and this would probably be a bug.

In your case it's probably a bit like this (simplified):
The existing cells in your document reference the style with `index 0`. You now create a new style with `index 1` and apply it to the row via `setRowStyle`.
All not existing(*1*) and new cells will then use the style with `index 1`. The existing cells however still point to the style with `index 0`, because they have not automatically been assigned the new style.

You probably expected `setRowStyle` to behave like the *Excel* application, where you can select the entire row and set the style on it. But that's not how it works. You have to iterate manually and apply the change to all cells.

---

`1`: Cells that exist only logically in the *Excel* application but not yet physically in the data structure in order to save space. This is why `getCell` can return `null` and doesn't just return `CELL_TYPE_BLANK` by default.